# How to call a method with local parameter from other class

Tags: java, class, parameters, call

I have written a simple program that is to take wind speed in km/h and convert that into Knots or Beaufort and state weather the wind is an European storm or calm.  The starting speed needs to be entered into the main class, but I cannot transfer it to the second class. Also, I am having difficulties calling the second class methods from the main.

My main class :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WindSpeedTester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter speed in km/hr.");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double input = kb.nextDouble();

        WindStorm windSpeed = new WindStorm();

        System.out.println("What would you want wind speed in?");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for km/hr, 2 for Beaufort, 3 for Knots, or 4 to exit.");

        int count = kb.nextInt();

        if (count < 0){
            while (count <0)
                System.out.println("Invalid input . Please enter a valid integer.");
                count = kb.nextInt();}
        else{
            while (count != 4 ){
                if (count == 1){
                    windSpeed.getKilometerPerHour(kilometersPerHour);}
                else if (count == 2){
                    windSpeed.getBeaufort(kilometersPerHour);}
                else if (count == 3){
                    windSpeed.getKnots(kilometersPerHour);}
                else if (count == 4){
                    System.out.println("Bye.");
                    System.exit(0);}
                else{
                    System.out.print("Invalid input.");}
        }
    }
    windSpeed.isCalm(kilometersPerHour);
    windSpeed.isOrcan(kilometersPerHour);
    kb.close();
    }
}
```

`WindStorm` class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WindStorm {

/**
 * the wind speed in kilometer per hour
 */
private double kilometerPerHour = 0.0;

public double windSpeed(double kilometerPerHour){
    double windSpeed = kilometerPerHour + input; //input is in main
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (windSpeed < 0){
        System.out.println("The wind speed entered is invalid. Enter another speed.");
        windSpeed = kb.nextDouble();}
    kb.close(); 
    return windSpeed;
}


/**
 * Return true if this wind speed is a
 * European windstorm (Orcan, more than
 * 120 km/h).
 */
public boolean isOrcan(double kilometersPerHour) {
    boolean isOrcan = true;
    if (kilometersPerHour > 120)
        System.out.println("The wind speed is Orcan.");
    return isOrcan; 
}
/**
 * Return true if this wind speed is
 * calm (less than 2 km/h).
 */
public boolean isCalm(double kilometersPerHour) {
    boolean isCalm = true;
    if (kilometersPerHour < 2)
        System.out.println("The wind is calm.");
    return isCalm;
}
public double getKilometerPerHour(double kilometersPerHour) {
    double getKilometerPerHour = kilometersPerHour; 
    System.out.println("The wind speed is: " + kilometersPerHour + " km/h.");
    return getKilometerPerHour;
}
/**
 * Returns the wind speed measured in knots (nautic miles).
 * A nautic mile is 1.852 kilometer.
 */
public double getKnots(double kilometersPerHour) {
    double getKnots = kilometersPerHour / 1852;
    System.out.println("The wind speed is: " + getKnots + "Knots (nautical miles).");
    return getKnots;
}
/**
 * Returns the wind speed measured in Beaufort (int 1-12).
 */
public int getBeaufort(double kilometersPerHour) {
    int getBeaufort = (int) Math.pow((kilometersPerHour / 3.01), (2/3));
    getBeaufort = (int) (getBeaufort + 0.5);            
        if (getBeaufort > 12)
            System.out.println("Invalid measurement.");
        else if (getBeaufort <= 0)
            System.out.println("Invalid measurement.");
        else
            System.out.println("The wind speed is: " + getBeaufort + "Knots.");
    return getBeaufort;
}
}
```

Running this code, I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907) 
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530) 
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456) 
at WindStorm.kilometersPerHour(WindStorm.java:15) 
at WindStorm.isOrcan(WindStorm.java:29) 
at WindSpeedTester.main(WindSpeedTester.java:26)
```

Comment: The exception you get doesn't seem to match the code you give.

Comment: The WindStorm class here doesn't compile.  So most likely, what you're running is actually an earlier version of it, which was left in your target directory.